# Cannot passing data when update image React JS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I using Laravel, Inertia JS, and React JS, i have problem when I trying to update picture, and send data to Controller Laravel but the problem is in Controller i wont detect data that i passed, i tried to dd($request->all()) and it only show empty array "[]", I have to console.log my data before request to backend, and it showed all.

There's my Code
UploadPhoto.jsx (Upload Image Component)

```
export default function UploadPhoto({ className = '', ...props }){
    return (
        <div className="py-4">
            <input {...props} className={'block text-sm text-gray-900 border border-black cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none' + className} aria-describedby="file_input_help" id="img" type="file"/>
            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500" id="file_input_help">PNG, JPG Only.</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

EditPage.jsx :

```
import DropdownList from "@/Components/DropdownList";
import InputLabel from "@/Components/InputLabel";
import UploadPhoto from "@/Components/UploadPhoto";
import AdminLayout from "@/Layouts/AdminLayout";
import { Head, router } from "@inertiajs/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function CategoryCreate(props){

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.project.title)
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(props.project.description)
    const [category_id, setCategory] = useState(props.project.category_id)
    const [link_github, setLinkGithub] = useState(props.project.link_github)
    const [link_behance, setLinkBehance] = useState(props.project.behance)
    const [link_dribbble, setLinkDribbble] = useState(props.project.dribbble)
    const [img, setImg] = useState(props.project.img)

    
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const data = {
            title,
            description,
            category_id,
            link_github,
            link_behance,
            link_dribbble,
            img,
        }
        
        router
            .put(`/admin/project/${props.project.id}`, data)

    }

    return (
        <AdminLayout>
            <Head title="Edit Project"></Head>
            <div className="py-6">
                <div className="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="title" value="Title" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <input className="block w-[500px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" placeholder="Title" onChange={(title) => setTitle(title.target.value)} defaultValue={props.project.title}/>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="description" value="Description" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <textarea className="block w-[500px] h-[150px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" placeholder="Description" onChange={(description) => setDescription(description.target.value)} defaultValue={props.project.description}/>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="category" value="Category" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <select className="block w-[500px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" onChange={(category_id) => setCategory(category_id.target.value)}>
                            <option value={props.project.category_id}>{props.project.category.name_category}</option>
                            <DropdownList category={props.category}/> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="link_github" value="Github" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <input className="block w-[500px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" placeholder="Link Github" onChange={(link_github) => setLinkGithub(link_github.target.value)} defaultValue={props.project.link_github}/>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="link_behance" value="Behance" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <input className="block w-[500px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" placeholder="Link Behance" onChange={(link_behance) => setLinkBehance(link_behance.target.value)} defaultValue={props.project.behance}/>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="link_dribbble" value="Dribbble" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        <input className="block w-[500px] mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" placeholder="Link Dribbble" onChange={(link_dribbble) => setLinkDribbble(link_dribbble.target.value)} defaultValue={props.project.dribbble}/>
                    </div>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="img" value="Image" className="text-xl"/>
                    <UploadPhoto className="w-[500px]" onChange={(img) => setImg(img.target.files[0])}/>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="img" value="Previous Image" className="text-xl"/>
                    <div className="py-4">
                        {props.project.img ? (<img src={`/storage/${props.project.img.substring(7)}`} width="50%" alt="Project Image" />) : (<p className="font-semibold">No Image Yet!</p>)}
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()} className="px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit">
                        Edit Data
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AdminLayout>
    )
}
```

ProjectController.php :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (@$request->file('img')) {
            $img = $request->file('img')->store('public/img');
            Project::findorFail($id)->update([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'category_id' => $request->category_id,
                'link_github' => $request->link_github,
                'link_behance' => $request->link_behance,
                'link_dribbble' => $request->link_dribbble,
                'img' => @$img,
            ]);
        } else {
            Project::findorFail($id)->update([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'category_id' => $request->category_id,
                'link_github' => $request->link_github,
                'link_behance' => $request->link_behance,
                'link_dribbble' => $request->link_dribbble,
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('project.index')->with('success', 'Project berhasil dirubah!');
    }
```

Sorry for bad english, but i really need your help, thank you

Comment: could you please share your inputlabel component? I think I know the issue but need to see that first.

Answer (score 0):

in your onChange you may not be grabbing the right information. the examples in their documentation point to `setData(event.target.files[0])`. Also I am not sure if the put method is supported when used this way. However, Laravel should allow you to circumvent this by doing

```
router.post('update/route', {
    _method:'put'
    img: form.img
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You be use `_method:'put'` and your route method be `post`,in my case I use this and it work:

```
const { data, setData, post} = useForm({
        _method:'put',
        title: props.title,
        ...
    });

const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        router.post(route('route.update',props.id ),data, {forceFormData:true});
    };
```